# Flutter - PageView with indicator stay in two indicators

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm building a carousel using pageView, and when it reaches the last index, it doesn't update to the last indicator, and it stays in two at the same time. This only happens on the last index.

I'm trying to use this snippet to tell the indicator that it should update to the last index, instead of staying on two at the same time:

```
  double get _offset {
    try {
      var offset = controller.page!;
      if (offset > (count - 2) && offset < (count - 1)) {
        var innerOffset = controller.page!;
        int newOffset = innerOffset.toInt() + 1;
        while (offset < newOffset) {
          innerOffset = innerOffset + 0.0001;
       
          return innerOffset % count;
        }
        return innerOffset % newOffset;
      } else {
        return offset % count;
      }
    } catch (_) {
      return controller.initialPage.toDouble();
    }
  }
```

The problem with the indicator

[image]

This is what I have in mind:
what I want to happend

[image]

Comment: As usual, most of my questions never get answers from this platform. Any ways, the answer to above problem is using Scopped Model or Inherited widgets

Answer (score 0):

You should check if the current page index is greater than or equal to the last index, and if so, returns the last index. If not, it proceeds with the existing calculation:

```
double get _offset {
  try {
    var offset = controller.page!;
    if (offset >= count - 1) {
      return count - 1;
    } else if (offset > (count - 2) && offset < (count - 1)) {
      var innerOffset = controller.page!;
      int newOffset = innerOffset.toInt() + 1;
      while (offset < newOffset) {
        innerOffset = innerOffset + 0.0001;
        return innerOffset % count;
      }
      return innerOffset % newOffset;
    } else {
      return offset % count;
    }
  } catch (_) {
    return controller.initialPage.toDouble();
  }
}
```